# Can I group several GitHub repos together for permission management?

Tags: github

I have 10+ teams and 50+ repos in an organization account. The goal is to group selected repos into a `management unit` so I can grant access to teams with fine permission.

The members of the teams will keep changing roughly monthly.

Question

1. Is this possible?
2. If not, what's the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

An [organization](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/collaborating-with-groups-in-organizations) is itself a group of repositories.

You can [manage team access to an organization repository](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/managing-team-access-to-an-organization-repository) or [to all repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/setting-base-permissions-for-an-organization), not to a group of repositories inside that organization.
You would need to define one organization per group of repositories in order to grant access for said groups.